# Managing wordpress Themes & plugins for multisite

Tags: plugins, theme-development, multisite, child-theme

I have a multisite with subdirectory setup.

`mainsite.com` will have a woocommerce shop and a blog.

`mainsite.com/support` is intended as a separate blog site for faq or other support articles that are not of much importance.

I have made a theme with woocommerce support and custom `front-page.php` for `mainsite` and so far it is working as intended.

I want similar design for `mainsite.com/support`. **Should I have to create a new theme for this site?**

Right now, I used the same theme but `front-page.php` is taking over homepage of this subsite but I want `mainsite.com/support` show blog posts.

Another issue is, I don't want woocommerce and some other plugins for this subsite. I realize that only way to disable plugin on subsite is adding some code in `functions.php`, which means I need to make seperate theme for subsite ?

What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: We have a 1 question per question policy, remember this is a Q/A site not a discussion forum, and loading your question with multiple sub questions significantly reduces your chances of getting good questions. There's nothing stopping you clicking on `Ask Question` and writing new questions, you don't have to ask them all at once

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck at this for hours. But apparently solution is more easier than I had expected.

I don't have to create new theme for the subsite.

To make subsite homepage show blog posts instead of custom `front-page.php`, I went to Settings > Reading and selected static page and set posts page to "Blog" and left homepage with nothing selected.

To enable plugin management for individual sites, I went to Network Settings and checked "Enable administrations menus".

Now I can manage plugin for the subsite without have to add any specific codes to `functions.php`.

Since Woocommerce is going to be disabled in the subsite, only change I had to make is to update sections of code in the theme that is relying on woocommerce functions ( such as title section in `header.php` ) to check if Woocommerce is active.

Comment: that is frustrating - something like that could be enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

> I want similar design for mainsite.com/support. Should I have to create a new theme for this site?

If you can reuse the existing theme great, if you can create a child theme great, **it's up to you and there is no correct answer here**

> Right now, I used the same theme but front-page.php is taking over homepage of this subsite but I want mainsite.com/support show blog posts.

Have you considered not using a subsite and having a blogs page named `support`? Or copying the theme and not using `front-page.php`?

> Another issue is, I don't want woocommerce and some other plugins for this subsite. I realize that only way to disable plugin on subsite is adding some code in functions.php, which means I need to make seperate theme for subsite ?

This suggests you've not setup the site at all, that's not how multisites work. To disable a plugin on a site you go to plugins and click disable. Multisites are no different.

If on the other hand you've put WooCommerce inside your theme, and not in a plugin, then that is a major grave mistake. Remove WooCommerce and install it as a plugin as it's supposed to be installed. Themes are for templates and visuals, you should not embed plugins inside them

Comment: I figured it out. Plugin management was not available for my subsite because the administration menus was not checked.